# Python updating global list based on another list

Tags: python, list

I'm struggling to re-work a bit of code that I have to perform a slightly different function. Basically I have a list:

```
totalRank = [['P1'], 0], [['P2'], 0], [['P3'], 0], [['P4'], 0], [['P5']]
```

I also have a second similar list:

```
playerPoints = [['P1', 5], ['P2', 5], ['P3', 0]. ['P4', 0]]
```

What I am wanting to do is update the players in the list 'totalRank' based on their points in the 'playerPoints' list, the desired outcome is:

```
totalRank = [['P1'], 5], [['P2'], 5], [['P3'], 0], [['P4'], 0], [['P5', 0]]
```

Below is the code I have to do this:

```
global totalRank
totalRank = [[[a], b+dict(playerPoints).get(a, 0)] for [a], b in totalRank]
```

This code does work however, the desired effect is not to add the points from the 'playerPoints' list to the 'totalRank' list but to update them or 'make them equal to' if that makes sense? So for example, the next 'playerPoints' list to come through may be:

```
playerPoints = [['P1', 20], ['P2', 20], ['P3', 10]. ['P4', 0]]
```

and the desired outcome for the 'totalRank' list is:

```
totalRank = [['P1'], 20], [['P2'], 20], [['P3'], 10], [['P4'], 0], [['P5'], 0]]
```

Whereas currently my code would produce the list:

```
totalRank = [['P1'], 25], [['P2'], 25], [['P3'], 10], [['P4'], 0], [['P5'], 0]]
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I have been struggling for quite a while now!

Comment: From the scenario you are describing, it seems to me that two dictionaries might be more appropriate than two lists. Perhaps you should consider changing the lists to dictionaries in this project if that is feasible?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! Unfortunately it won't be, the 'playerPoints' list is manipulated and created through my project and the 'totalRank' list basically acts as a list that will keep a log of points for each player and is updated each time a new 'playerPoints' list is created

Comment: It appears your brackets are off for the two bottom lists, working on an answer now.

Comment: my answer should solve the problem without a dictionary.

Comment: Can you rely on the fact that `totalRank` and `playerPoints` will be in the same order (that is, that `totalRank[n][0][0] == playerPoints[n[[0]` for all n)?

Comment: Also, I don't understand why your reply to jaguar means you can't change these both to dicts. One is manipulated and created through your project—you can do that with a dict just as easily as a list. The other keeps a log of points for each player and is updated each time a new `playerPoints` is created—that can be a dict too, and would be conceptually simpler that way (and make this code and other code easier to write and more efficient).

Comment: If you remove `b+` wouldn't it give desired output?

Comment: I have actually tried this but unfortunately not, this gets rid of other previous scores in the 'totalRank' list whenever a new list comes in. So for example, if 'P5' has 5 points in 'totalRank' and a new 'playerScores' list comes in that does not have 'P5' in it, then the score is removed from 'totalRank' list when updated

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
totalRank = [[['P1'], 0], [['P2'], 0], [['P3'], 0], [['P4'], 0], [['P5']]]
playerPoints = [['P1', 5], ['P2', 5], ['P3', 0], ['P4', 0]]
final_d = dict(playerPoints)
new_data = [[[a], b[0]+final_d.get(a, 0) if b else final_d.get(a, 0)] for [a], *b in totalRank]
```

Output:

```
[[['P1'], 5], [['P2'], 5], [['P3'], 0], [['P4'], 0], [['P5'], 0]]
```

Edit: the solution does work with additional input:

```
totalRank = [[['P1'], 5], [['P2'], 5], [['P3'], 0], [['P4'], 0], [['P5'], 0]]
playerPoints = [['P1', 20], ['P2', 20], ['P3', 10], ['P4', 0]]
final_d = dict(playerPoints)
new_data = [[[a], b[0]+final_d.get(a, 0) if b else final_d.get(a, 0)] for [a], *b in totalRank]
```

Output:

```
[[['P1'], 25], [['P2'], 25], [['P3'], 10], [['P4'], 0], [['P5'], 0]]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I tested this out however it gives the same result as my previous code. So when the next 'playerPoints' list comes through it adds the result on rather then updating it to the new result. For example, if the next 'playerPoints' list that comes through has values of 10, then the 'totalRank' or 'new_data' list values of 5 are 15 rather than 10

Comment: @Sean I see now your intended output. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Sean Glad to help! Please see my recent edit. The solution does work when presented with a different input list.

Comment: Hey sorry I think I wasn't very clear in my description of the desired output. The desired output would be 
    [[['P1'], 20], [['P2'], 20], [['P3'], 10], [['P4'], 0], [['P5'], 0]]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
totalRank = {'P1': 0, 'P2': 0, 'P3':0, 'P4': 0, 'P5':0}
playerPoints = {'P1':5,'P2':5,'P3':0,'P4':0}

for key in playerPoints.keys():
    totalRank[key] = playerPoints[key]

print(totalRank)
```

This will have the output:

```
[[['P1'], 5], [['P2'], 5], [['P3'], 0], [['P4'], 0], [['P5'], 0]]
```

The power of dictionaries is that this code will work for any key that you enter into playerPoints. The format of a dictionary is `{key1 : value1, key2 : value2, key3 : value3}` and so on. Keep this in mind when you are adding playerPoints.

Comment: Hey I've tried this out however, it seems to only update the first x amount of players in the 'totalRank' list where x is the amount of players in the 'playerPoints' list. So for example, if the 'playerPoints' list is: [[P1, 10], [P12, 10], [P19, 10]] it updates the 'totalRank' list to: [[P1], 10], [[P2], 10], [[P3, 10]]

Comment: @Sean Hmm, this code is more difficult without a dictionary. Are you sure either totalRank or playerPoints cannot be a dictionary, or both have to be lists?

Comment: It could potentially work with dictionaries yeah, i'm just not too sure how to do it myself as I have not been programming very long

Comment: @Sean dictionaries would allow the program to be much simpler, I am editing the answer with dictionaries now.

Comment: Hey the help is much appreciated! I'm now trying to change some stuff in my code that will allow me to implement these as dictionaries instead of the lists

Comment: Ok let me know if you need more help. Please accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Hey I am having some trouble changing my program to work with dictionaries. Is there a way I can convert the two existing lists into dictionaries to make this work? The problem I am having is I am not hard coding the lists so at the start of my program the list 'playerPoints' is actually empty and has players and points added to it during the program which I am then wanting to store in the 'totalRank' list

Comment: I can see the logic behind what is trying to be achieved with the dictionaries though, is there anyway that would be possible with lists? Like for example looping through the 'totalRank list to see if the player name exists in the 'playerPoints' list and if it does, make the value in the 'totalRank' list equal to the value in the 'playerPoints' list for each player if that makes sense?

Comment: @Sean Sorry I'm not able to see your full code, if you could  paste it and provide a link I could help you better, dictionaries are simpler than lists and easier to use in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me with your specified values of playerLists.

```
def updateList(totalRank, playerPoints):

    for plist in playerPoints:
        pkey = plist[0]
        pvalue = plist[1]

        for j in range(len(totalRank)):
            tkey = totalRank[j][0]
            tvalue = totalRank[j][1]
            if pkey in tkey:
                totalRank[j][0] = pkey
                totalRank[j][1] = pvalue

    return totalRank

### Input starts here

totalRank = [[['P1'], 0], [['P2'], 0], [['P3'], 0], [['P4'], 0], [['P5']]]
playerPoints = [['P1', 5], ['P2', 5], ['P3', 0], ['P4', 0]]

### take care of key without explicit value, e.g. 'P5' with no value
for list in totalRank:
    if len(list) == 1:
        list.append(0)

print ("totalRank = ", totalRank)

totalRank = updateList(totalRank, playerPoints)
print ("totalRank = ", totalRank)

playerPoints = [['P1', 20], ['P2', 20], ['P3', 10], ['P4', 0]]
totalRank = updateList(totalRank, playerPoints)
print ("totalRank = ", totalRank)
```

Sample output from above run using your inputs:

```
totalRank =  [[['P1'], 0], [['P2'], 0], [['P3'], 0], [['P4'], 0], [['P5'], 0]]
totalRank =  [['P1', 5], ['P2', 5], ['P3', 0], ['P4', 0], [['P5'], 0]]
totalRank =  [['P1', 20], ['P2', 20], ['P3', 10], ['P4', 0], [['P5'], 0]]
```

Note that the [[['P1',x],... has changed to [['P1',x].. but the values are valid.